# what interface does lpsched provide that cups does not?

Tags: centos, printing, cups, system-v, lp

Work has a Linux stock/erp custom system that uses the Unix System V (Solaris, SCO, HP-UX) lpsched program that someone who used to work here compiled for RHEL/CentOS 5 i686 (I have no idea why or how).  From a system admin point of view this is pain in the neck to install, and support on new CentOS 6+ x86_64 systems as it requires copying old binaries from old systems, and just putting up with the bugs.

I see that cups provides the commands

- lp
- lpadmin
- lpc
- lpoptions
- lpq
- lpr
- lprm
- lpstat
- cancel

What way can a program use lpsched that is not already provided by cups?  Note that large parts of the custom software we run rely on the ability to send printer language (Kyocera prescribe) as is to the printer over the network to the printer's print queue.

Essentially I'd like to remove our reliance on this messed up situation and just be able to use cups for all printing.

Comment: You can setup raw queues to send raw printer language to CUPS.